# Ошибка 429 при парсинге с сайта

Tags: python, html, parse

Всем здравствуйте. Недавно написал программу, которая ищет контерпики для доты. Написал вручную словари, в которых описаны преимущества одного героя над другим. Но дело в том, что при каждом патче эти данные будут меняться, а их переписывать очень долго, поэтому хотел написать парсинг, чтобы не мучиться. Но тут появилась другая проблема, связанная с ошибкой 429 (Too many requests). Как я понял это сработала защита от DDOS-атак. Вот мой код:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

allheroes = {'Dark Seer': 0, 'Shadow Demon': 0, 'Slark': 0, 'Pangolier': 0, 'Ancient Apparition': 0,
             'Outworld Destroyer': 0, 'Monkey King': 0, 'Lina': 0, 'Razor': 0, 'Undying': 0, 'Necrophos': 0,
             'Alchemist': 0, 'Rubick': 0, 'Keeper of the Light': 0, 'Lich': 0, 'Io': 0, 'Anti-Mage': 0,
             'Earthshaker': 0, 'Death Prophet': 0, 'Marci': 0, 'Lone Druid': 0, 'Winter Wyvern': 0,
             "Nature's Prophet": 0, 'Lycan': 0, 'Tinker': 0, 'Sniper': 0, 'Vengeful Spirit': 0, 'Hoodwink': 0,
             'Oracle': 0, 'Kunkka': 0, 'Underlord': 0, 'Tidehunter': 0, 'Grimstroke': 0, 'Dawnbreaker': 0,
             'Enchantress': 0, 'Drow Ranger': 0, 'Centaur Warrunner': 0, 'Bristleback': 0, 'Broodmother': 0,
             'Primal Beast': 0, 'Lion': 0, 'Terrorblade': 0, 'Shadow Fiend': 0, 'Pugna': 0, 'Medusa': 0, 'Leshrac': 0,
             'Phantom Assassin': 0, 'Viper': 0, 'Timbersaw': 0, 'Warlock': 0, 'Windranger': 0, 'Phantom Lancer': 0,
             'Muerta': 0, 'Techies': 0, 'Bloodseeker': 0, 'Huskar': 0, 'Invoker': 0, 'Nyx Assassin': 0, 'Riki': 0,
             'Elder Titan': 0, 'Snapfire': 0, 'Zeus': 0, 'Sven': 0, 'Lifestealer': 0, 'Ember Spirit': 0, 'Tiny': 0,
             'Clockwerk': 0, 'Magnus': 0, 'Sand King': 0, 'Visage': 0, 'Dragon Knight': 0, 'Chaos Knight': 0,
             'Dark Willow': 0, 'Weaver': 0, 'Gyrocopter': 0, 'Meepo': 0, 'Tusk': 0, 'Crystal Maiden': 0,
             'Earth Spirit': 0, 'Omniknight': 0, 'Night Stalker': 0, 'Luna': 0, 'Disruptor': 0, 'Witch Doctor': 0,
             'Morphling': 0, 'Mars': 0, 'Juggernaut': 0, 'Doom': 0, 'Treant Protector': 0, 'Spirit Breaker': 0,
             'Dazzle': 0, 'Chen': 0, 'Wraith King': 0, 'Mirana': 0, 'Brewmaster': 0, 'Phoenix': 0, 'Naga Siren': 0,
             'Ogre Magi': 0, 'Storm Spirit': 0, 'Jakiro': 0, 'Pudge': 0, 'Troll Warlord': 0, 'Slardar': 0,
             'Beastmaster': 0, 'Void Spirit': 0, 'Shadow Shaman': 0, 'Templar Assassin': 0, 'Queen of Pain': 0,
             'Faceless Void': 0, 'Venomancer': 0, 'Puck': 0, 'Bane': 0, 'Legion Commander': 0, 'Enigma': 0, 'Ursa': 0,
             'Bounty Hunter': 0, 'Clinkz': 0, 'Skywrath Mage': 0, 'Arc Warden': 0, 'Spectre': 0, 'Axe': 0,
             'Silencer': 0, 'Batrider': 0, 'Abaddon': 0}

# this what i have
antimage = {}

# and this what i want after parse
# antimage = {'Meepo': 9.7, 'Lone Druid': 4.53, 'Phantom Assassin': 4.34, 'Troll Warlord': 4.18, 'Slardar': 3.7,
#             'Legion Commander': 3.66, 'Huskar': 3.56, 'Terrorblade': 3.54, 'Monkey King': 3.46, 'Lina': 3.31,
#             'Earthshaker': 3.01, 'Shadow Fiend': 2.77, 'Templar Assassin': 2.75, 'Bloodseeker': 2.71, 'Io': 2.64,
#             'Enchantress': 2.63, 'Riki': 2.57, 'Hoodwink': 2.51, 'Beastmaster': 2.5, 'Tiny': 2.5, 'Ursa': 2.4,
#             'Pangolier': 2.39, 'Puck': 2.23, 'Night Stalker': 2.22, 'Slark': 2.22, 'Axe': 2.06, 'Marci': 1.98,
#             'Kunkka': 1.96, 'Sven': 1.88, 'Nyx Assassin': 1.84, 'Drow Ranger': 1.79, 'Viper': 1.67, 'Elder Titan': 1.63,
#             "Nature's Prophet": 1.63, 'Disruptor': 1.54, 'Weaver': 1.42, 'Clinkz': 1.38, 'Chen': 1.23, 'Enigma': 1.2,
#             'Earth Spirit': 1.18, 'Windranger': 1.15, 'Dawnbreaker': 1.14, 'Venomancer': 1.08, 'Jakiro': 1.08,
#             'Luna': 1.04, 'Snapfire': 1.0, 'Ember Spirit': 1.0, 'Crystal Maiden': 0.98, 'Naga Siren': 0.8,
#             'Alchemist': 0.74, 'Phoenix': 0.72, 'Shadow Shaman': 0.7, 'Dazzle': 0.68, 'Spirit Breaker': 0.67,
#             'Mirana': 0.66, 'Shadow Demon': 0.59, 'Bounty Hunter': 0.59, 'Broodmother': 0.58, 'Doom': 0.57,
#             'Visage': 0.55, 'Grimstroke': 0.55, 'Silencer': 0.54, 'Techies': 0.5, 'Bane': 0.47,
#             'Centaur Warrunner': 0.47, 'Outworld Destroyer': 0.43, 'Timbersaw': 0.42, 'Magnus': 0.39, 'Tusk': 0.37,
#             'Rubick': 0.33, 'Sniper': 0.28, 'Batrider': 0.24, 'Lion': 0.14, 'Lycan': 0.11, 'Witch Doctor': 0.07,
#             'Lifestealer': 0.03, 'Keeper of the Light': -0.03, 'Warlock': -0.13, 'Primal Beast': -0.14,
#             'Dark Willow': -0.17, 'Invoker': -0.18, 'Muerta': -0.4, 'Treant Protector': -0.45, 'Vengeful Spirit': -0.46,
#             'Dragon Knight': -0.51, 'Death Prophet': -0.73, 'Undying': -0.75, 'Leshrac': -0.75, 'Chaos Knight': -0.8,
#             'Faceless Void': -0.8, 'Queen of Pain': -0.92, 'Void Spirit': -0.92, 'Dark Seer': -1.0, 'Tidehunter': -1.03,
#             'Bristleback': -1.04, 'Abaddon': -1.06, 'Skywrath Mage': -1.13, 'Oracle': -1.19, 'Necrophos': -1.25,
#             'Sand King': -1.33, 'Mars': -1.34, 'Pudge': -1.47, 'Omniknight': -1.5, 'Morphling': -1.51,
#             'Ogre Magi': -1.65, 'Underlord': -1.69, 'Razor': -1.75, 'Lich': -1.79, 'Pugna': -1.81, 'Brewmaster': -1.87,
#             'Phantom Lancer': -1.91, 'Clockwerk': -1.99, 'Gyrocopter': -2.15, 'Juggernaut': -2.17,
#             'Winter Wyvern': -2.49, 'Ancient Apparition': -2.67, 'Arc Warden': -2.82, 'Wraith King': -2.82,
#             'Tinker': -3.01, 'Storm Spirit': -3.36, 'Zeus': -3.54, 'Spectre': -4.22, 'Medusa': -6.98}

# searching counters for Anti-Mage hero
# (for example, but i want to search counters for all heroes automatically)
url = "https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/anti-mage/counters"

# THATS MY PROBLEM
# Error: Too many requests 429
r = requests.get(url)

print(r.status_code)
# 429

# please help
```

Comment: Попробуйте посылать на сайт хедеры, имитируя браузер. Например, библиотеку `fake useragent` можно использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0',
           }
response = requests.get('https://www.dotabuff.com/heroes/anti-mage/counters', headers=headers)
print(response)

<Response [200]>
```

Либо использовать специальную библиотеку для генерации реалистичного `User-Agent`. Установка:

```bash
!pip install fake-useragent
```

Код:

```py
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': ua.random})
```